# Is DX11VideoRenderer thread safe?

Tags: directx, directx-11, ms-media-foundation, hardware-acceleration, dxva

I'm using the Microsoft sample **DX11VideoRenderer** to render real time video in Windows 10. When I run just one stream, the video looks great. However when I run more than 4 or 5 streams, some of the video in their respective windows start blanking out intermittently. The effect can be over just a portion or all of each video window.

Also I get a few intermittent errors from this function call in my log file:

```
hr = pVideoContext->VideoProcessorBlt(m_pVideoProcessor, pOutputView, 0, 1, &StreamData );
```

The error returned is: *E_INVALIDARG    One or more arguments are not valid 0x80070057*

I'm only using the **Presenter.cpp** and **display.cpp** modules of the **DX11VideoRenderer** in my code. The source is located at:
[DirectX video rendering sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DX11VideoRenderer)

My initial suspicion at this stage is that DXVideoRenderer may not be thread safe. I found this information about multithreading: [Introduction to Multithreading in Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which states:

> While the use of a device context (ID3D11DeviceContext) is not thread-safe, the use of a Direct3D 11 device (ID3D11Device) is thread-safe.

But it seems that since I'm using separate instances of the **CPresenter** class for each window, there should not be a problem with **ID3D11DeviceContext** not being thread safe because each window should have it's own instance of **ID3D11DeviceContext**.

Does anyone have any experience or ideas about this DX11VideoRenderer software sample and what might be causing this problem?

Thank you!

**-UPDATE-**

I have been able to duplicate the problem with just one window so it no longer appears to be a threading issue. If I manually resize the window many times I can sometimes get the video in the window to flicker. When this happens I see in my log that the same function call to `VideoProcessorBlt()` had a failure with the same return code, *E_INVALIDARG*.

Comment: Are you creating a new device for each window or just a deferred context? If you are using distinct contexts with a single device one or more of them is a deferred context, and likely video renderer can't draw to a deferred context. To get multiple immediate contexts, you need multiple device instances.

Comment: Maybe one or more arguments are indeed invalid? Maybe some other part of your program suffers from thread-safety related issue?

Comment: I don't think DX11VideoRenderer has threading issues, but it does not necessarily mean that your using portions of this code is also thread safe. Overall I think the question is put wrong here. If you are using the renderer as a complete primitive then we discuss its thread safety, otherwise the question is about your code and there is no sufficient detail provided in this sense.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I am calling CPresenter::SetVideoWindow() for each new window. This calls CPresenter::CreateDXGIManagerAndDevice() which then calls D3D11CreateDevice() which creates a new device for each window.

Comment: @VTT I quickly checked the pointer values in the call parameters to VideoProcessorBlt() and they are all the same as when the function call succeeds. I will need to examine the structures that the pointers are referring to in more detail to see if there is a difference there.

Comment: @RomanR. It no longer appears to be a threading issue. Please see my update in my OP. I will try to isolate the relevant portions of my code and give more details.

Answer (score 1):

> If I manually resize the window many times I can sometimes get the video in the window to flicker. When this happens I see in my log that the same function call to VideoProcessorBlt() had a failure with the same return code, E_INVALIDARG.

This behaviour is not documented by Microsoft.

The problem is the same with DirectX9, but the error occurs with IDirect3DDevice9::Present, just after VideoProcessBltHD.
The HRESULT code is 0x88760872, and 0x88760872 is not documented.

So when resizing window, the error can occur.

See [H264Dxva2Decoder](https://github.com/mofo7777/H264Dxva2Decoder) :

In Dxva2Renderer.cpp, check for HANDLE_DIRECTX_ERROR_UNDOCUMENTED.

The strategy I choosed is to pause the video if playing (see WindowsFormProc and WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE/WM_SYSCOMMAND),
also, this avoid flickering.

Doing this, the error disappears.

PS: normally this error can be safely ignored.

I think this error is just there to tell you that when the window is resized, the underlying API is struggling to synchronize the DirectX presentation with your HWND, which changes size quickly.